# How to update the UI when items inside DropDownButtonFormField changes?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobx

I was working with `DropDownButtonFormField2` **where the items come from the API call**.

The problem is, when the API call is finished, the dropdown list items are not updated.
**After the API call is finished, I already called `setState()`**. **But the item list is not updated**, I need to go to other screen and go back to refresh the dropdown.
I am using `mobx` btw.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

**my_screen.dart**

```
class MyScreenState extends State<MyScreen> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async => false,
      child: Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        body: _buildItemDropDown(),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _my_store.getItemList().then((value) {
      setState(() {});
    });
  }


_buildItemDropDown() {
    return DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
        key: UniqueKey(),
        child: DropdownButtonFormField2(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        isDense: true,
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
        ),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: ColorPalette.green[400]!)),
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: ColorPalette.black[200]!)),
      ),
      isExpanded: true,
      hint: const Text(
        'Options',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
      ),
      iconOnClick: SvgPicture.asset(
        'assets/svg/arrow_drop_down_activated.svg',
      ),
      icon: SvgPicture.asset(
        'assets/svg/arrow_drop_down.svg',
      ),
      iconSize: 30,
      isDense: true,
      buttonHeight: 40,
      buttonPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12, right: 12),
      dropdownDecoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
      ),
      items: obsItemSpec.asMap().entries.map((item) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: item.value,
          enabled: false,
          child: StatefulBuilder(
            builder: (context, menuSetState) {
              final _isSelected = selectedItems.contains(item.value);
              return InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  _isSelected
                      ? selectedItems.remove(item.value)
                      : selectedItems.add(item.value);
                  setState(() {});
                  menuSetState(() {});
                },
                child: Container(
                  color: (item.key % 2 != 0)
                      ? ColorPalette.white[400]
                      : ColorPalette.white[500],
                  height: double.infinity,
                  padding:
                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18.0, vertical: 0),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      _isSelected
                          ? SvgPicture.asset(
                              'assets/svg/checkbox_green_outlined.svg',
                            )
                          : SvgPicture.asset(
                              'assets/svg/checkbox_outlined_blank.svg',
                            ),
                      const SizedBox(width: 10),
                      Text(
                        item.value,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 14,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      }).toList(),
      itemPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      value: selectedItems.isEmpty ? null : selectedItems.last,
      validator: (value) {
        if (value == null) {
          return 'Please select gender.';
        }
      },
      onChanged: (value) {},
      selectedItemBuilder: (context) {
        return obsItemSpec.map(
          (item) {
            return Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0.0),
              child: Text(
                selectedItems.join(', '),
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 14,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                ),
                maxLines: 1,
              ),
            );
          },
        ).toList();
      },
    ));
  }
```

**my_store.dart**

```
part 'my_store.g.dart';

class MyStore = _MyStore with _$MyStore;

abstract class _MyStore with Store {

@observable
Observable<List<ItemSpec>?> obsItemSpec = Observable<List<ItemSpec>?>(null);


@action
Future getItemList() async {
 final future = _useCase.getItemList();
    future.then((itemList) {
      obsItemSpec = Observable(itemList.map((list) =>
          ItemSpec(list.name, list.id)).toList());
    });
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your `then` method inside of `initState` executes before your `future.then` is done inside of `getItemList` method because you are not awaiting your future inside it nor returning it. So I suggest something like this:

```
@action
Future getItemList() async {
  final itemList = await _useCase.getItemList();
  obsItemSpec = Observable(
      itemList.map((list) => ItemSpec(list.name, list.id)).toList());
}
```

Comment: yes, i forgot to use await. and also, thanks for explaining it.

Answer (score 1):

hi i suggest instead of use

```
  _my_store.getItemList().then((value) {
     setState(() {});
});
```

make function like :

```
     getStoreData() async {

       await  _my_store.getItemList();
       setState(() {});
    
  }
```

then call it inside initState:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getStoreData();
   
  }
```

if you get error like you called setstate before or during build
do:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
       WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
       getStoreData();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

SetState() in initState won't work properly all the time. You can move function `_my_store.getItemList().then((value) { setState(() {}); });` to `didChangeDependencies()` which gets called after full state has been set, or better yet wrap `_buildItemDropDown()` in futureBuilder and pass `_my_store.getItemList()` as said future. Until connection done you can display loading indicator of disabled dropdown and after data is received futureBuilder will rebuild to show proper dropdown with received info.